# My sql query to get product count for Attribute

Tags: magento2, database, magento2.4, eav-attributes

I need the mysql query for the following magento code. Need to get the count of products with the given brand option id.

```
count($this->productCollectionFactory->create()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addFieldToFilter('status','1')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('brand','120')
                ->load()->getData());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me to get the query string

```
  $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addFieldToFilter('status','1')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('brand','120');
            $collection->getSelect()->__toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use `echo $collection->getSelect()`
Example:

```
$collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addFieldToFilter('status','1')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('brand','120')
                ->count();
echo $collection->getSelect();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addFieldToFilter('status','1')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('brand','120');
echo $collection->count();
```